# If sentence Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i tried to look in the highcharts api, didn't find an answer, is there any way to set a rule inside the highcharts function of creation, lets say if one of my series is not coming properly from the server but the other series coming ok - i would like to present only the ones that's are ok  - 
at the moment i get exception and it won't show me the graph at all,
this is my series's:

```
series:[{
    name: 'class1',
    data: [class1[0],class1[1],class1[2],class1[3]]
},
{
    name: 'class2',
    data: [class2[0],class2[1],class2[2],class2[3]]
}, {
    name: 'class3',
    data: [class3[0],class3[1],class3[2],class3[3]]
},
{
    name: 'class4',
    data: [class4[0],class4[1],class4[2],class4[3]]
}, {
    name: 'class5',
    data: [class5[0],class5[1],class5[2],class5[3]]
}]
```

so for example if the data for class4 coming wrong from the server i get exception :(

Comment: Can't you just check before creating chart, if series is correct? And don't add the series to the chart.

Comment: yeah its possible, but i would like to show the chart anyway with the good series's and without the faulty one...

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Check series before creating chart and use only correct ones.

Comment: but if i have 4 series's and one is faulty i need to write the combination of all the series's that are ok? no?

Comment: What is the message of the exception? Could you show example of wrong data from server?

Answer (score 2):

You should check that your data is valid before you pass it to the chart.

Right above where you create the chart, simply loop through your series.data, and make sure it is not empty, and that it fits all of your other criteria.